# Пишу телеграм бота. Как сделать так чтобы бот ждал ввода данных, а после этого он продолжал действия?

Tags: python

Пример работы:

1. Бот пишет привет
2. Юзер пишет в ответ
3. Бот запрашивает число
4. Бот выдаёт случайное число, сравнивает его с введенным и взависимости от выданного числа пишет you win или you lose

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью такой конструкции, я сделал на примере команды старта, пользователь вводит **/start** и выходит **Текст**, далее пользователь вводит текст и выполняется функция **start_2**.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def inserting_text_cars(message):
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Текст')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, start_2)

def start_2(message):
    #Что нужно выполнить
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!